# Firebase validation rules - empty data validation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to identify a rule that will validate that a JSON dataset has been passed. I'm trying to use the Simulator but am unable to work it out.

Data (JSON) used:

```
{}
```

Validation rule tried:

```
".validate": "newData.val() != null && newData.exists()"
```

This passes as a successful write. I also tried them each uniquely with the same result.

I read elsewhere that apparently validate rules only apply to non-empty datasets and one needs to put the rules into the write rules?

I couldn't understand that, as I thought write is for WHO can write and validate is WHAT they can write.

Help?

**Update 1**

I've refactored the rules as follows, but this still produces a successful write:

```
".write": "newData.exists()"
```

Comment: OK. Just realised my two rules above are functionally the same, but that still doesn't enlighten me on why it successfully passes validation.

Comment: Validation rules don't run on delete operations. If you want to disallow deletes you must put that in a `.write` rule. Also see Michael's explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359735/why-dont-validate-security-rules-get-run-when-data-is-removed-from-firebase

Comment: Yes but I tried that under Update 1. Is that rule there incorrect?

Comment: Nope. But there's many ways you can use that rule incorrectly. Please update your question to include the [complete-but-minimal rules and code that will reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).